# safari engine problem with arabic lang when style of letter change

Tags: html, css, safari, arabic, arabic-support

I have this problem when I try to color one letter in the text the character returns to the default shape in the font like in the image.
[image]

note that I use a custom font that behaves normally in most other browsers(in devices other than ios), and the default color should be transparent

the HTML

```
<p class="idhar-rule">ٱ<span class="idhar">لۡ</span>كِتَٰبُ</p>
```

css

```
.idhar {
    color: #EB2A2D;
}
.idhar-rule {
    color: transparent !important;
font-family: 'idharFont';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 4.2vw;
}
```

other notes:

- color is transparent to layer p on top of each other so that different Arabic grammar rules have different color and font families.
- font-family changes because some colored letters need to be colored without the mark above or under it so a custom font is created and the mark removed from it.
- there is a separation between the letters that are not colored.
- can't use (&zwj;) to join letters because it stops the font from using its feature to get the correct combination and shape of the combined litter. it just gets the default bind of the two letters next to each other.

can someone tell me why this problem happens and how to fix it? thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, see: https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/qBQyMEz Both lines look exactly the same to me, apart from the red color for one character. This might depend on the exact font you're using, your OS or browser. I've tried Chrome and Firefox on Windows 11.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware try ios device iphone or mac or use safari browser https://prnt.sc/S0E77H1OkT8R

Comment: @KIKOSoftware no problem talk your time, thanks for the effort.

Comment: I can confirm that the red character is indeed shown separately on safari in iOS 12.5.7.

Comment: I investigated this and can confirm it is a known issue in Safari. It was reported as a [webkit bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6148) in 2005 and they still haven't solved it. My advice is to not rely on the font rendering engine of browsers when you want to add these details. See also [Text Rendering Hates You](https://faultlore.com/blah/text-hates-you/#style-can-change-mid-ligature). I have had outstanding browser bugs for years as well, and they just don't get solved because no-one thinks it is important enough.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I see what you are saying so what can I use other than browsers to render HTML
by the way, another search engine like Google works properly in this case. can I use Chrome on iPhone or Mac and make them render the font I tried but failed. somehow it use Safari engine under the hood.

Comment: Yes, Apple forces other browsers to use Webkit as well, no choice there. Although: [read this](https://9to5mac.com/2023/02/07/new-iphone-browsers/). The obvious alternative to text rendering by browsers is to just use images.

Answer (score 0):

Add [zero-width joiner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_joiner) before and after the span.

```html
<p class="idhar-rule">ٱ&zwj;<span class="idhar">&zwj;لۡ&zwj;</span>&zwj;كِتَٰبُ</p>
```